# Transfer file between iPhones using Bluetooh

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, data-transfer

Can I transfer data between two iPhones via Bluetooth?

Comment: Only if you have previously installed 1 app in each iPhone. And non-jailbroken options will only allow them to work with same app on the other side.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

There's an AppStore app called [Bluetooth Fileshare](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bluetooth-fileshare/id353705432?mt=8) ($0.99), but it has very low reviews. Also, check out [Bluetooth Photo Share](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bluetooth-photo-share/id326109583?mt=8) (free) if you're only interested in transferring photos.

If you have a jailbroken iPhone, you can use [iBlueNova](http://www.iphoneincanada.ca/iphone-news/bluetooth-file-transfer-for-iphone-with-ibluenova-2-0) ($5.99), but there might be better/free ways to do file transfer if you're already jailbroken.

Answer (score 0):

If you jsut want to transfer images/contact details etc Bump is a good app, it also works cross platform too.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use AirDrop? You can transfer a lot of information pretty fast and don't require any new software to be loaded?